# Populate Text Box with ComboBox

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I am looking to simply populate a text box with a value based on a ComboBox in Acrobat Pro.  The following code is attached to custom calculation script to the text box.  In addition, 'Commit selected value immediately' is applied to the 'employeeName' field.

I am getting back nothing.  Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

```
    var employeeName = this.getField("employeeName").value;
    if (employeeName=="M. Smith") event.value = "30";
    else if (employeeName=="D. Johnson") event.value = "29";
    else if (employeeName=="J. Davis") event.value = "86";
    else event.value = "";
```

Note: Names have been changed to protect the innocent, and obviously have zero relevance to the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, I'd use a switch statement for this number of conditions but the following should work...

```
var employeeName = this.getField("employeeName").value;
if (employeeName == "M. Smith") {
    event.value = "30";
}
else if (employeeName == "D. Johnson") {
    event.value = "29";
}
else if (employeeName == "J. Davis") {
    event.value = "86";
}
else {
    event.value = "";
}
```